# How to send created PDF as attachment?

Tags: asp.net, pdf

Here is my code:

```
    Dim doc As Document = New Document
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\1.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    doc.Open()
    doc.Add(New Paragraph("REQESTOR"))
    doc.Add(New Paragraph("Joe Shmoe"))
    doc.Close()

    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("SMTP.com")
    Dim mail As New MailMessage("ESHM@cgn.com", "Joe.Shmoe@ncgn.com", "Test", "Hi")

    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
    attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("~/1.pdf")
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)


    Try
        smtp.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ss As String
        ss = ex.Message
    End Try
```

I create a new pdf doc then I try to send that pdf doc as an attachment in an email. But when I run this code I get an error:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\1.pdf'
Is there anyway to send that created pdf doc as an attachment in an email???

Thank you for the help

Comment: Doesn't the error explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\1.pdf` isn't a valid path. Change your code to this:

```
attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/1.pdf"))
```

.NET will resolve the path to your file for you that way (assuming you actually have a file called `1.pdf` in the root of your site).